# Get parent keys in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I looked through some other answers but I don't fully understand. There are no duplicate values.

```
{
  "type": "champion",
  "data": { 
    "89": {
      "title": "the Radiant Dawn",
      "name": "Leona"
    },
    "110":{
      "title": "the Arrow of Retribution",
      "name": "Varus"
    }
  }
}
```

what I have, I'm not sure how to proceed. In the actual dict there's more information than just title and key

```
championID = 0
for key, value in championData["data"].items():
    for childkey,childvalue in value.items():
        #
champion = getChamp(championID)
```

I want to input a name and have it return the ID (the number, 89 and 110 are listed). For example, inputting Leona would return 89.

(Sorry, I could have done a better job of asking the question at the beginning :'v)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Why do u wanna do tht anyway? `dict` is not intended to be used so.
if u wanna iterate u may use `for k,v in mydict.iteritems()`

Comment: sorry, I've edited in what I have

Comment: Please post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
championData = {"type": "champion", "data": {
    "89": {
        "title": "the Radiant Dawn",
        "name": "Leona"
    },
    "110": {
        "title": "the Arrow of Retribution",
        "name": "Varus"
    }
}}

name = "Leona"
data = championData['data']
for championId in data:
    if(data[championId]['name']) == name:
        print(championId)
```

The output is: 89

Comment: Wow, I was really overcomplicating it. This is what I was looking for, thank you!